# How to diplay a hexadecimal emoji in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, emoji

I would like to display the emoji `&#x1f911`; while only having the hexadecimal value of it.

```dart
var line = "testing is forever &amp;#x1f911;";

Text(
  "${line}",
  style: TextStyle(
      fontSize: 14,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      color: Color(0xFF008080)),
),
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope its helpful to you. Refer Unicode Charecter [here](http://unicode.org/Public/emoji/1.0/emoji-data.txt)

```
Text(
     '\u{1F602}',
     style: TextStyle(
             fontSize: 25,
            ),
     ),
```

Your Result screen-> [image]

**Or** in **`VS Code`** Pressed **`Window`** `+` **`.`** and open the emoji picker box choose your wanted emoji and select it

```
Text(
   '',
    style: TextStyle(
     fontSize: 30,
    ),
   ),
```

Your result screen-> [image]

Comment: sorry I think my question was not clear, I mean I would like to display the emoji provided within a String 

eg Text(
"testing is forever &#x1f911;",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Color(0xFF008080)),)

Comment: @Adonis I think in flutter write hexadecimal values in above answer `Text('testing is forever \u{1f911}',),` and put your style and color as well

Comment: so if the string is provided by API I'll first have to locate the hex value then format it ?

Comment: Yes, can you tell me which format do you save emoji string?

Comment: the website saves the emoji in hex but when I try using it on mobile (using dart) it shows the hex value and not the emoji

Comment: your hex format is like `&#x1f911` ? if its yes then declare it in above format

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by using the HtmlCharacterEntities and the HtmlUnescape

HtmlUnescape().convert(HtmlCharacterEntities.decode("testing is forever &#x1f911;"))